# Is there any difference between event values I can get from Android app and iOS app through FCM BigQuery export feature?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging and its BigQuery export feature for my native app on both iOS and Android.
When I see data in BigQuery, I see `MESSAGE_DELIVERED` as a value of event for Android app. But for iOS app, there's no `MESSAGE_DELIVERED`.
Is there any difference between event values I can get from Android app and iOS app?
I see `MESSAGE_ACCEPTED` for both iOS and Android app, so it seems it sends any other data correctly.